# JSON language file extension that allows to edit JSON file by key from code

Tags: visual-studio, vs-extensibility

I have a large JSON file with translations. For now let's assume that it looks like this:

```
{
"key0": "text0",
"key1": "text1"
}
```

In many functions I have calls like: `foo("key0", true);` `boo("key", 0f, 1f, false);`

Is there any extension that allows at least see (or better edit) the value for the key?

For example if I hover over "key0" in function foo it will show a popup "text0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created [JSONEx](https://github.com/RARgames/JSONExtension) - Visual Studio Extension that does exactly what I need.

Feel free to use it or modify it if you need.

Right now it's only working on the JSON with "en" in structure like in the sample project in the test directory. 
Currently, I don't provide the check for correct JSON structure, but I'll implement it soon.

If you need to change it to fit your file structure, it's quite easy, just a few code changes and recompile, but if you need any guidance, just open github ticket.